# Nodal circles on spherical harmonics

Tags: quantum-mechanics, homework-and-exercises, spherical-harmonics

**Homework question:**
For the spherical harmonic with $l=2$, $m=0$ , at what angle theta relative to the polar axis is the nodal circle in the northern hemisphere?

**My attempted answer:**
I know that I need to find the values of $\theta$ for which the function is equal to zero. $Y(2,\theta) = 0$ and solving for $\cos(\theta)$, I got $3\cos^2(\theta) - 1 = 0$, $\cos(\theta) = \pm√(1/3)$ and so $\theta$ = around $109.47$° and $70.52$°. So for the northern hemisphere, I picked $109.47$° as my answer but it is not the answer. What is my mistake here? Thank you.

Comment: what is the range of theta in the N hemisphere?

Comment: No information about that, only the information that I have given above was the full question sadly.

Answer (score 1):

Remember the north pole is at $\theta=0°$, the equator is at $\theta=90°$,
and the south pole is at $\theta=180°$.

From this you know which solution to pick for the northern hemisphere.